# Problems in parwise comparisons in nested factors

Tags: r

This is a dataset were week is nested in period, this gets problematic when I want to see pairwise comparisons between Diet and week. What does the error "Try taking nested factors out of 'by'." mean?

```
form <- as.formula(paste(colnames(df)[8],'~ Diet  + period +week*Diet +(1|id)')) #get data for interactions
    dflmer <- lmer(form, data=df)
    a <- Anova(dflmer, type=3) 
    library(emmeans)
    emm <- emmeans(dflmer, pairwise ~ Diet | week) 

    NOTE: A nesting structure was detected in the fitted model:
  week %in% period
Note: Grouping factor(s) for 'week' have been added to the 'by' list.
Error in .nested_contrast(rgobj = object, method = method, by = by, adjust = adjust,  : 
                            There are no factor levels left to contrast. Try taking nested factors out of 'by'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since week is nested in period, you can't condition on week without also conditioning on period. Try

```
emmeans(dflmer , pairwise ~ Diet | period:week)
```

The very latest version, 1.46, of **emmeans** fixes this, in that older versions did not consider the possibility of nesting in `by` variables.

### Addendum

I think I'm remembering some details wrong. The code that generates this error message was misplaced in versions <= 1.4.5. I think you may need to install version 1.4.6 to get this to work. See [the related issue report](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/186)

### Addendum 2

I constructed a similar example, and I got errors from this model still. The problem is that `week` is nested in `period`, and the model has `Diet` crossed with `week` but not with `period`, which doesn't make sense. I *was* able to get results after I fitted the model with fixed-effect terms `Diet*(period + week)`